# How to design like below picture using SWT which is fixed in all display screen size?

Tags: eclipse, swt, e4

I am trying to design just like below image using swt. I used FormLayout where I need to give width and height which is fixed for all screen size. But i want to resize based on screen size. How do I implemented it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `GridLayout` using enough intermediate composites:

```java
// Assumes 'parent' has FillLayout which will be the case for an e4 part

Composite outer = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);

outer.setLayout(new GridLayout());

Composite intermediate = new Composite(outer, SWT.NONE);
intermediate.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

intermediate.setLayout(new GridLayout());

Composite inner = new Composite(intermediate, SWT.NONE);
inner.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, true));

inner.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, false));

Label label1 = new Label(inner, SWT.LEAD);
label1.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.RIGHT, SWT.CENTER, false, false));
label1.setText("TopLevelPath");

Text text1 = new Text(inner, SWT.SINGLE | SWT.BORDER);
text1.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false));

Label endLabel = new Label(inner, SWT.PUSH);
endLabel.setText("but1");

endLabel = new Label(inner, SWT.PUSH);
endLabel.setText("but2");

Label label2 = new Label(inner, SWT.LEAD);
label2.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.RIGHT, SWT.CENTER, false, false));
label2.setText("Alt TopLevelPath (optional)");

Text text2 = new Text(inner, SWT.SINGLE | SWT.BORDER);
text2.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false, 3, 1));
```